# Is the LIKE operator case-sensitive with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, varchar, sql-like

In the [documentation about the LIKE operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx), nothing is told about the case-sensitivity of it. Is it? How to enable/disable it?

I am querying `varchar(n)` columns, on an Microsoft SQL Server 2005 installation, if that matters.

Comment: It depends on the collation of your column (or database). If it is case sensitive, then `LIKE` is case sensitive, if it's not, then `LIKE` is not

Comment: Check the documentation about SQL-Server collations http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want it to be case sensitive, or not case sensitive?

Comment: Case sensitivity defaults to the collation on the column which defaults to the one on the database. It is get roundable mostly, which way do you want to go?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

It is not the operator that is case sensitive, it is the column itself.

When a SQL Server installation is performed a default collation is chosen to the instance. Unless explicitly mentioned otherwise (check the collate clause bellow) when a new database is created it inherits the collation from the instance and when a new column is created it inherits the collation from the database it belongs.

A collation like `sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as` dictates how the content of the column should be treated. CI stands for case insensitive and AS stands for accent sensitive.

A complete list of collations is available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx

**(a) To check a instance collation**

```
select serverproperty('collation')
```

**(b) To check a database collation**

```
select databasepropertyex('databasename', 'collation') sqlcollation
```

**(c) To create a database using a different collation**

```
create database exampledatabase
collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as
```

**(d) To create a column using a different collation**

```
create table exampletable (
    examplecolumn varchar(10) collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as null
)
```

**(e) To modify a column collation**

```
alter table exampletable
alter column examplecolumn varchar(10) collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as null
```

It is possible to change a instance and database collations but it does not affect previously created objects.

It is also possible to change a column collation on the fly for string comparison, but this is highly unrecommended in a production environment because it is extremely costly.

```
select
  column1 collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as as column1
from table1
```

Comment: It seems the range of characters like `[A-Z]` is always case-insensitive. `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSŠTUVWXYZŽÅÄÖ]` however seems to obey collation.

Comment: Also, you can query the case sensitivity of a particular column with something like this: `select COLLATION_NAME, iif(cast(COLLATIONPROPERTY(COLLATION_NAME, 'ComparisonStyle') as int) & 1 = 0, 'case sensitive', 'case insensitive') from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = 'exampletable' and COLUMN_NAME = 'examplecolumn'`

Comment: @jumxozizi I added your suggestion to the answer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I added your suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 24):

All this talk about collation seem a bit over-complicated. Why not just use something like:

```
IF UPPER(@@VERSION) NOT LIKE '%AZURE%'
```

Then your check is case insensitive whatever the collation

Comment: Because this isn't sargable. Your example uses a variable and a leading wildcard. But against a column indexed with a case insensitive collation `like 'a%'` could use the index and the `upper` version couldn't.

Comment: The question was whether or not `like` operator is case sensitive.

Comment: You need to know the collation, otherwise doing this could be pointless. For instance, if the column being queried against uses `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, then doing `UPPER(@@VALUE) NOT LIKE '%SOMETHING%'` or `@@COLUMN NOT LIKE '%SOMETHING%'` is irrelevant: result would be the same.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to achieve a case sensitive search without changing the collation of the column / database / server, you can always use the `COLLATE` clause, e.g.

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(bar VARCHAR(32) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS);
GO
INSERT dbo.foo VALUES('John'),('john');
GO
SELECT bar FROM dbo.foo 
  WHERE bar LIKE 'j%';
-- 1 row

SELECT bar FROM dbo.foo 
  WHERE bar COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS LIKE 'j%';
-- 2 rows

GO    
DROP TABLE dbo.foo;
```

Works the other way, too, if your column / database / server is case sensitive and you don't want a case sensitive search, e.g.

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(bar VARCHAR(32) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS);
GO
INSERT dbo.foo VALUES('John'),('john');
GO
SELECT bar FROM dbo.foo 
  WHERE bar LIKE 'j%';
-- 2 rows

SELECT bar FROM dbo.foo 
  WHERE bar COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS LIKE 'j%';
-- 1 row

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.foo;
```

Comment: Beware in the last query if you use `WHERE bar COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS LIKE '[j-k]%'` it will return `John` as in this collation capital `J` is between lowercase `j` and lowercase `k`. It's like `aAbBcC...jJkKlLmM...` which is not obvious. It seems `Latin1_General_BIN` is more predictable with range searches w/ LIKE operator.

Comment: This is the answer that helped ME

Answer (score 15):

The `like` operator takes two strings.  These strings have to have compatible collations, which is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179886%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

In my opinion, things then get complicated.  The following query returns an error saying that the collations are incompatible:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where 'abc' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS like 'ABC' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

On a random machine here, the default collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.  The following query is successful, but returns no rows:

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where 'abc' like 'ABC' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

The values "abc" and "ABC" do not match in a case-sensitve world.

In other words, there is a difference between having no collation and using the default collation.  When one side has no collation, then it is "assigned" an explicit collation from the other side.

(The results are the same when the explicit collation is on the left.)

Comment: Can you reproduce the error against a table that is NOT a system object like INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES?

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . Yes I can.  Is the database broken ;) ?

Comment: Don't know, I'm on a mobile device right now and can't spin up a Windows VM. I just don't know that your entire description is technically accurate.

Answer (score 14):

You have an option to define *collation order* at the time of defining your table. If you define a case-sensitive order, your `LIKE` operator will behave in a case-sensitive way; if you define a case-insensitive collation order, the `LIKE` operator will ignore character case as well:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    CI_Str VARCHAR(15) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS -- Case-insensitive
,   CS_Str VARCHAR(15) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS -- Case-sensitive
);
```

Here is a [quick demo on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/005388/4) showing the results of collation order on searches with `LIKE`.

Answer (score 5):

Try running,

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION')
```

Then find out if your collation is case sensitive or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can change from the property of every item.

[image: case sensitive]

Answer (score 0):

You can easy change collation in Microsoft SQL Server Management studio.

- right click table -> design.
- choose your column, scroll down i column properties to Collation.
- Set your sort preference by check "Case Sensitive"