# SQL Field Calculation based on CASE if then else

Tags: sql, sql-server, field, calculated-columns

I am trying to calculate a field. For example

```
select **sum(New)** as NewCST where WHERE PO ='L22411301' AND ItemNo IN('1730','1343').
```

Instead of the sum I have this whole case statement to implement. I have not done a formula calculation that has this many conditions. So any help is appreciated.

So far I got this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 
    Case
        When  PO_SIZE like ‘%lb%’ Then  CONVERT(decimal(13,4), NET_COST / TOTAL_WEIGHT)
        When PO_SIZE like ‘%LB%’ Then  CONVERT(decimal(13,4), NET_COST / TOTAL_WEIGHT)
        Else  CONVERT(decimal(13,4), ADJ_EXT_NET_COST / LINE_QUANTITY)        
from [FirstStrike_Retail].[custom].[Whse_Line_Item] )End AS NewCst.
WHERE PO ='L22411301' AND ItemNo IN('1730','1343')
```

Comment: fyi: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962419/is-the-like-operator-case-sensitive-with-ms-sql-server) for case-sensitivy of `LIKE`. You can also combine `LIKE` tests, e.g. `when PO_Size like '%lb%' or PO_Size like '%oz%' then Net_Cost / Total_Weight` so that you don't need to repeat the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for the outer select statment. Also, you need to close the `CASE` statement with the `END` keyword before you get to the `FROM` clause.

Here is a tidied-up version of your code.

```
SELECT  Case    When PO_SIZE like ‘%lb%’ Then  CONVERT(decimal(13,4), NET_COST / TOTAL_WEIGHT)
                When PO_SIZE like ‘%LB%’ Then  CONVERT(decimal(13,4), NET_COST / TOTAL_WEIGHT)
                Else  CONVERT(decimal(13,4), ADJ_EXT_NET_COST / LINE_QUANTITY)
        End AS NewCst
from    [FirstStrike_Retail].[custom].[Whse_Line_Item] )
WHERE   PO ='L22411301' 
AND     ItemNo IN('1730','1343')
```

Answer (score 1):

The first solution definitely has syntax errors.  I guess the question I have do you want a calculation at the row level (declan_k) or at the grouping level (sonam).

However, there is some redundancy in the above code (solutions).  Also, a *"Lb"* for a PO_SIZE will not calculate correctly.

Let's have some fun!

I always like to create a sample database when doing these answers.

```
-- Sample table
CREATE TABLE #WHSE_LINE_ITEM
(
  ITEM_ID INT,
  PO_NUM VARCHAR(10),
  ITEM_NUM VARCHAR(10),
  NET_COST REAL,
  ADJ_EXT_NET_COST REAL,
  LINE_QUANTITY INT,
  TOTAL_WEIGHT REAL,
  PO_SIZE VARCHAR(10)
);

-- Sample data
INSERT INTO #WHSE_LINE_ITEM
VALUES
(1, 'L22411301', '1730', 200.00, 0.0, 3.0, 15.0, 'LB'),
(2, 'L22411301', '1730', 150.00, 0.0, 3.0, 30.0, 'lb'),
(3, 'L22411301', '1343', 100.00, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 'LN');
```

I did a calculation at the row level.  I hope this is what your were looking for.

```
-- Calculate field using case stmt
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN (LOWER(PO_SIZE) like '%lb%') THEN 
        CAST((NET_COST / TOTAL_WEIGHT) AS DECIMAL (13,4))
    ELSE
        CAST((NET_COST / LINE_QUANTITY) AS DECIMAL (13,4))
  END AS NEWCST, 
  *
FROM 
  #WHSE_LINE_ITEM
WHERE 
  PO_NUM = 'L22411301' AND 
  ITEM_NUM IN('1730','1343');
```

When looking at code, I always try reduce the size to a minimum.  If you are testing for all combinations of pound (Lb, lB, lb, or LB), why not convert to a lower case string before the pattern match?

The resulting query results are below.

[image]

Food for thought, if you are running this query many times over the day, you might want to have a persisted computed field.

Check out the [MSDN entry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) for 2012.  This will save the engine from having to calculate the field every time at the expense of storing the results on disk.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   sum(Case When  PO_SIZE like ‘%lb%’ Then  CONVERT(decimal(13,4), NET_COST / TOTAL_WEIGHT)
   When PO_SIZE like ‘%LB%’ Then  CONVERT(decimal(13,4), NET_COST / TOTAL_WEIGHT)
   Else  CONVERT(decimal(13,4), ADJ_EXT_NET_COST / LINE_QUANTITY)END)NewCst 
from 
   [FirstStrike_Retail].[custom].[Whse_Line_Item] 
WHERE 
   PO ='L22411301' AND ItemNo IN('1730','1343')
```