# Query Match is Case Sensitive

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, case-insensitive

I have the following query, looking for salespeople of `'BG'`.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[JobOrders]
  where [salesperson] = 'BG'
```

When I use `'bg'` instead, I do not get results.  To my understanding `'BG'` or `'bg'` would bring back the same results.

Is there a setting that would prevent this?

Comment: which database is this?

Comment: Depends on your collation pf your Sql Server install. See this [question and answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962419/is-the-like-operator-case-sensitive-with-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this situation you can always check using Upper cases

```
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[JobOrders]
  where upper([salesperson]) = 'BG'
```

Comment: Valid answer but be aware that the benefit of any indexes will likely be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Your `salesperson` column is almost certainly a foreign key and so would likely be populated by consistently cased values (ie they should be all upper case), so:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[JobOrders]
WHERE [salesperson] = UPPER('bg')
```

This would allow an index to still be used for the `salesperson` column.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it case insensitive by using collation:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[JobOrders]
where [salesperson] = 'BG' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: OP wanted case insensitive results.