# mySQL: pattern matching 3 or more "a's" in name

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

This is the table I am working with...

[image]

I am trying to "Find the countries that have three or more a in the name".

Here is my current code...

```
SELECT name FROM world
  WHERE name LIKE '%aaa%'
```

`world` contains `name` and `continent`.

Am I even close?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initial attempt will only match countries that have three adjacent `a`s in the name. Try the following:

```
SELECT name FROM world
  WHERE name LIKE '%a%a%a%'
```

The character `a` matches only the character `a` (case sensitivity depends on the table and server, for [MS SQL at least](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962419/is-the-like-operator-case-sensitive-with-ms-sql-server)). The character `%` will match any number of characters, any number of times. The seven characters in my query will mean that there are at most seven groups. For example:

`Afghanistan` is broken into , `A`, `fgh`,`a`,`nist`,`a`, and `n`.

`Algeria` is broken into , `A`, `lgeri`, `a`, , and then there is no remaining `a` to include, so it is not included as a match.

`Madagascar` could be broken into `Mad`, `a`, `g`, `a`, `sc`, `a`, and `r`. Note that the first group contains an `a`, because `%` allows any character, including `a`. (Here I assume the pattern matching is greedy, which means it makes the capture groups as large as possible, which prefers earlier groups to later groups.)

Comment: That works, I don't understand why though. I understand why a country with three "a"'s would come out correct, but how does this code include the "or more" part of the problem?

Comment: @ea87 Expanded the answer to explain how `%` will work for three countries, which will hopefully illustrate that. It would be more difficult to match exactly three `a`s than three or more `a`s--the simplest way would be to include a NOT LIKE to exclude four or more `a`s.