# Select letters where they are not preceeded or followed by letters e.g. FIND Ag or *Ag but not SAG or MAGNET

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, search, pattern-matching

I need to find the characters **Ag** in a column comprised of a variety of string lengths/string positions but where **Ag** does not form part of a word (e.g. S**AG**, i.e. **Ag** is not preceded and/or followed by any letters [A-Z]).

I have tried

```
WHERE AttributeColumn LIKE '%[^A-Z]AG[^A-Z]%'
```

but it excludes results when Ag has no other character before or after (i.e. string only contains **Ag**). Perhaps a `REGEXP` with the * function? So that **Ag** can be preceded and/or followed by zero or more of [A-Z]...

If this could work can you provide me with an example of the query for MS SQL?

Comment: What about punctuation e.g. is "The atomic symbol for silver is *Ag*, Argon is Ar" a match?

Answer (score 1):

What about about padding the searched string with valid separators e.g. spaces? e.g.

```
WHERE ' ' + AttributeColumn + ' ' LIKE '%[^A-Z]AG[^A-Z]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this?,

```
WHERE AttributeColumn LIKE '%[^A-Z]AG[^A-Z]%' 
    OR AttributeColumn LIKE 'AG[^A-Z]%' 
    OR AttributeColumn LIKE '%[^A-Z]AG' 
    OR AttributeColumn = 'AG'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just match the specific case of the search? If 'Ag' won't turn up in your results of course

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(bar VARCHAR(32) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS);
GO
INSERT dbo.foo VALUES('John'),('john');
GO
SELECT bar FROM dbo.foo 
WHERE bar LIKE 'j%';
-- 1 row

SELECT bar FROM dbo.foo 
WHERE bar COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS LIKE 'j%';
-- 2 rows

GO    
DROP TABLE dbo.foo;
```

More info here [Is the LIKE operator case-sensitive with MS SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962419/is-the-like-operator-case-sensitive-with-ms-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you? `([^A-Z]|\s)AG([^A-Z]|\s)`