# Using `_%` together in `LIKE` is not returning exact data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I can guesss it may be easy to answer type question but I am facing it first time, so any help will be more appreciated.

My Query:

```
SELECT remarks FROM enroll WHERE remarks LIKE 'REC_%'
```

OUTPUT:

```
remarks
REC_59161
Reclassify Hedge
```

Expected Output is only `REC_59161`. Yes `_` is used for matching any single character but I am just looking for achieving my expected output.

Comment: Underscore `_`, is a wildcard. Why don't you want Reclassify Hedge? Wrong case, or no underscore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_` is a **[wildcard Character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859(v=sql.90).aspx)**. So that you have to escape it using `[]`.

**Query**

```
select remarks
from enroll
where remarks like 'REC[_]%';
```

Answer (score 2):

The underscore `_` character is actually a special character with the `LIKE` operator, as are `%`, `[]` and `^`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql

In that article, you'll see that an underscore `_` matches any single character.

Use the `ESCAPE` keyword to define an escape character to allow you to escape the pattern-matching characters. We can use `!` as the escape character, so:

```
WHERE remarks LIKE 'REC!_%' ESCAPE '!'
```

Answer (score 1):

`_` is a wildcard character, Try this :

```
declare @enroll table (remarks varchar(50));
insert into @enroll values ('REC_59161') , ('Reclassify Hedge');
SELECT remarks FROM @enroll WHERE remarks LIKE 'REC[_]%';
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/QWDBJN55877)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. It seems that the column is *case insensitive*, see [Is the LIKE operator case-sensitive with MS SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962419/is-the-like-operator-case-sensitive-with-ms-sql-server) for details. That's why `Rec` in `Reclassify Hedge` fits `REC` in the `Like`
2. `_` (as well as `%`) is a *wild card*, you should *escape* `_` in the pattern

Query:

```
  SELECT remarks 
    FROM enroll 
   WHERE remarks LIKE 'REC*_%' ESCAPE '*' /* SQL 92 standard */
```

http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

> uses the triadic operator LIKE (or the inverse, NOT
>   LIKE), operating on three character strings and returning a Boolean.
>   LIKE determines whether or not a character string "matches" a given
>   "pattern" (also a character string). The characters **'%'** (**percent**)
>   and **'_'** (**underscore**) have *special meaning* when they occur in the
>   pattern. The optional *third argument* is a character string
>   containing exactly one character, known as the "*escape character*", for
>   use when a percent or underscore is required in the pattern *without
>   its special meaning*.