# What does like'%aa%' do in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

What does  `LIKE'%aa%'` exactly do?
Is it case-sensitive?

Comment: I assume you've already consulted the documentation. What aspect(s) are unclear to you?

Comment: it looks for a string that has two consecutive "aa" in it and returns the string

Comment: `col like '%aa%'` finds any string that has "aa" anywhere inside it.

Comment: Find value it having "a" anywhere in respective column

Comment: is 'aa' case sensitive ?

Comment: you have to check the collation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962419/is-the-like-operator-case-sensitive-with-ms-sql-server. Other wise you have convert on both sides

Comment: try this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: @UpasanaRoy it is case in-sensitive . ignore the negative votes. it is a good question :) . From next time frame the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It search for a record in which the field in the condition contains the literal, in this case `'aa'`.

For instance:

```
Select * from Employee
where Name like '%aa%'
```

It retrieves all employees where the names contains the literal `'aa'`..

Regards!!!

Answer (score 2):

The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column.

```
e.g. WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%aa%'
```

Finds any values that have "aa" in any position

Answer (score 1):

It retrieves all the strings having the VALUE = "aa" from DataBase.

Answer (score 1):

in a where clause it looks for anything which would contain 'aa'.

% acts a wildcard so anything can be before it or after it