# StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase cannot be translated while used in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am facing a problem executing the below query in .NET 6.

```
query = context.Where(user =>                       
                      user.Email.Contains(model.Email,
                      StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

After searching the web I understood that EF Core does translate Contains for server-side evaluation - but not the overload that accepts StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase or any other StringComparison. But never found the correct way to solve this issue

So I changed the query to something as follows to make it work:

```
query = context.Where(user =>
                      user.Email.ToLower().Contains(model.Email.ToLower());
```

Even though it is working I am not entirely happy with this solution and still wondering which solution solves my problem best. Would using `ToLowerInvariant()` be a better solution? Any better approach to solve this?

**UPDATE**

`ToLowerInvariant()` does not work and causes the same error caused by `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`

Comment: Did you try ToLowerInvariant? I have a hunch it won't be supported either.

Comment: If you can write a comparison that includes all you want, but also a few extras, I would run the final comparison in memory, after EF has done its thing.

Comment: what is your db provider?

Comment: If you are using SQL, it's going to ignore case by default already

Comment: If you are using SQL Server then you can force a specific collation, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity. I have not tried this with `.Contains()` but it's worth a try. Not sure if this is supported by other DB providers.

Comment: Case-sensitivity when translating to SQL is a database issue, not a C# issue. What database provider? How is your `Email` column's collation set?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I did try ToLowerInvariant(), which lead to the same error as using the string comparisons

Comment: @DanielA.White MySql

Comment: @PeterB checking this out

Comment: @NetMage it is not only about case sensitivity, its about InvariantCulture. While this worked fine with .NET 2.2, it is not being translated anymore into SQL since .NET 3.1. Here it is described why it is no longer supported

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/1222#issuecomment-611113142

Comment: Since you never had this run server-side it could be an option to force client-side evaluation yourself if you really want .Net semantics for comparison (and if the amount of data you pull is limited). If you don't want that it will always be a question of choosing a collation. No other option. Since it's about email addresses, that only allow a restricted range of characters, almost any case-insensitive collation will do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Net core EF 3.1 LINQ string comparison no longer working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59795841/net-core-ef-3-1-linq-string-comparison-no-longer-working)

Comment: You didn't mention you were comparing to EF Core 2.2. In 2.2, you were not translating to SQL - EF Core 2.x automatically switched from translation to client-side evaluation when it ran into untranslatable methods. When migrating to EF Core 3 or above, you can add a `AsEnumerable()` just before the untranslatable method to get the same result.

Comment: @sommmen thx for the link, but no this doesn't answer my question

Comment: @NetMage i will check this out, thx for the response

Comment: @NetMage `AsEnumerable()` actually doesn't work in my case, since I am expecting an IQueryable

Comment: You can put `AsQueryable()` at the end even though it is really an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @GuevaraBrik did you find a solution? I'm having to enumerate before running the invariant culture comparison, potentially very costly :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your are writing your LINQ query on a DbSet. This is not possible as it cannot be translated to SQL statements.

You could however use the `EF.Functions.Like` function. This gets translated to the SQL provider and is by default case insensitive.

```
query = context.Where(user =>                       
                  EF.Functions.Like(user.Email, model.Email));
```

Comment: Is it really? Have you read this: [Is the LIKE operator case-sensitive with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14962419/1220550)

Comment: [According to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctionsextensions.like?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctionsExtensions_Like_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctions_System_String_System_String_) it is case insensitive when evaluated on the client.

Comment: To @klekmek: OP question is about an issue in translating an expression to SQL, which tells me that client side evaluation is not the case here. Also both this answer and my comment are about translation to SQL.

Comment: @klekmek I have tested your solution and the Like function is not case-insensitive, ToLower or ToUpper are definitely needed on both sides of the comparison in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

How your query reacts depends on the collation you set on the server side. After all your linq expressions will be translated into an SQL query and how that is interpreted will depend on your database and column settings.

What you could try is stating a collation in your query e.g.

```cs
var customers = context.Customers
    .Where(c => EF.Functions.Collate(c.Name, "latin1_general_ci collation") == "John")
    .ToList();
//SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS for SQL Server
//latin1_general_ci collation for MySQL
```

as found in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity#explicit-collation-in-a-query). Where `CI` stands for case-insensitive (opposed to `CS`). Be aware that this query won't be able to leverage the index on the `Name` due to the custom collation. So it would be better to define it on the column (or table/database).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
query = context.Where(user => EF.Functions.Collate(user.email, 
            "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI").Contains(model.Email));
```