# SQL WHERE LIKE query doesnt return correct records

Tags: sql, database

I have a database, and in it I store quite a lot of text. I want to run querys, where I search through these texts. But sometimes, when I write in a condition word for these texts, not all records are returned that should be.

In this image, you can see a record that has the word "Kizárólag" in it. : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwMHT.jpg

I tried writing this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `vissza_nem_teritendo_info1` 
WHERE `onalloan_tamogathato_tevekenysegek` LIKE '%kizárólag%'
```

But it only returned this record, not the other one. : https://i.stack.imgur.com/C659l.jpg

So I tried copy-pasting the word "Kizárólag" directly out of the record I need, and run the query like that.

You can see the results here. : https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ykh.jpg

I fiddled around a bit, and I found that the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `vissza_nem_teritendo_info1`
WHERE `onalloan_tamogathato_tevekenysegek` LIKE '%kizá%'
```

Returns both records. : https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4at3.jpg

The following (and from then on):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `vissza_nem_teritendo_info1` 
WHERE `onalloan_tamogathato_tevekenysegek` LIKE '%kizá%'
```

does not. : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mredm.jpg

I don't know if it's important, but the collation of the column is utf7mb4_0900_ai_ci :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z49wH.jpg

Any ideas why this is happening?

note: I tried adding images inside the post, but the site wouldn't let me.

Additional info: I made a new table, with a single column in it, with the same encoding as the column mentioned above. Into the column, I inserted the two cells from before (I copy pasted them over). They behave the same way to the above queries.

The interesting thing is: I made a third record in this new table, and instead of copying over the problematic cell (the one in the first picture), I typed it. Now, when I run the queries, I get that cell back, but not the original one (which i copied).

How is that?

Additional additional info:

I copy pasted the text from the original cell, and before inserting it into the dummy table, I deleted the word "Kizárólag", and typed it in myself, and inserted it. The above queries, when run, list this cell as well.

When I am looking at the list of records in the table, when I hover my cursor over a cell, a tooltip shows the 'original length' of the cell. The cell which I copy pasted has an original length of 90. The cell I copy pasted, then deleted the word "Kizárólag" and typed it in, has an original length of 88. The cell I typed it in by myself has an original length of 82.

Comment: I'd like to help. Would you be able to try a LIKE for a word with ASCII letters only? I.e add a couple of records with 'abc' in them, and see what you get when you query on that. I'm wondering if it's a character encoding issue. Ah, my apologies, I see you already did another query that worked.

Comment: Perhaps this may help explain more on the LIKE  operator and collations?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962419/is-the-like-operator-case-sensitive-with-mssql-server