# How to check if string contains just lowercase characters and numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, string, db2, constraints

How to check if the string contains just lowercase characters, numbers and the symbol "@" in SQL

Im trying something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1
    ADD CONSTRAINT c1
        CHECK (
            (R1 like '%[abcdefghijklmnobqrstuvwxyz@1234567890]%')
            );
```

Comment: i believe lower(R1) migh help. something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962419/is-the-like-operator-case-sensitive-with-sql-server

Comment: What's your Db2 platform and version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should phrase the check constraint as the column *not* having any characters which are *not* lowercase, numbers, or the `@` symbol:

```sql
ALTER TABLE TABLE1
ADD CONSTRAINT c1
    CHECK (NOT REGEXP_LIKE(R1, '[^abcdefghijklmnobqrstuvwxyz@1234567890]'));
```

Comment: Thanx but that does not works with me, idk why but DB2 cant find the function REGEXP_LIKE can you please rewrite it but with the function LIKE

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  S
, '>' || TRANSLATE (S, '*', ' abcdefghijklmnobqrstuvwxyz@1234567890') || '<' AS TRANSLATED
, CASE TRANSLATE (S, '*', ' abcdefghijklmnobqrstuvwxyz@1234567890') 
    WHEN '' THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO'
  END AS RES
FROM (VALUES ' abc', 'abc@123', 'Abc') T (S)
```

| S | TRANSLATED | RES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | >* < | NO |
| abc@123 | > < | YES |
| Abc | >A < | NO |