# Matching word repetition in string SQL with %

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

I want to select all texts having twice or more the string "JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE" in my column raw_text of my SQL database :

I used this command :
`WHERE raw_text LIKE '%JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE%JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE%'`

But this is one of the raw_text returned :

```
JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE
Paris , le 11/07/2022
Bonjour,
Vous voudrez bien trouver ci - dessous le justificatif de voyage concernant votre commande e - billet du
11/06/2022 .
Nous attirons votre attention sur le fait que ce justificatif ne constitue en aucun cas un titre de transport .
Départ / Arrivée TGV INQUI 6687 Date / Heure
PARIS GARE DE LYON 15/06 à 16h38
Montant du voyage 56,00 EUR
Dossier voyage QORXSD
LYON PART DIEU 15/06 à 18h56
TARIF LIBERTE- Carte Libené valide à présenter . Echange et remboursement sans frais jusqu'à 30 min apres
départ . Des 30 min avant départ , billet échangeable 2 fois max ( méme jour , même trajet ) et non remboursable
après 1 échange . Siemprunt d'un autre train , échange obligatoire
Ne - bile :
Référence client 
Nº FCE
Point de vente FRXMB
SNCF vous remercie de votre confiance .
2- CLASSE
1 A sur 1 0 Page 1/1
SNCF
SNCF Voyageurs , société anonyme au capital social de 157 780 980 euros - rue Jean - Philippe Rameau , 93200 Saint - Denis - RCS Bobigny n 519 037 584
```

The string 'JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE' (in uppercase) only appears one time, so why is it returned ?

Comment: Using MySQL/MariaDB or an other RDBMS ? If MySQL/MariaDB, the row is returned because it is case insensitive by default.

Comment: I am using SQLServer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the LIKE operator case-sensitive with SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962419/is-the-like-operator-case-sensitive-with-sql-server)

Comment: There's a typo in your text by the way: `méme jour` instead of `même jour`.

Comment: @AymDev Yes thank you, I just check and I use insensitiv collation

Comment: And that is why you get the row, there is part of the tsring which looks like `dessous le justificatif de voyage concernant`, which is the second match to `JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE`. If the casing is important, you need to `COLLATE` the value.

Answer (score 0):

Your text does contains twice the sentence "JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE"

1. first line
2. line 4

   DECLARE @raw_text VARCHAR(max) =

   'JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE

   Paris , le 11/07/2022

   Bonjour,

   Vous voudrez bien trouver ci - dessous le justificatif de voyage concernant votre commande e - billet du

   11/06/2022 .

   Nous attirons votre attention sur le fait que ce justificatif ne constitue en aucun cas un titre de transport .

   Départ / Arrivée TGV INQUI 6687 Date / Heure

   PARIS GARE DE LYON 15/06 à 16h38

   Montant du voyage 56,00 EUR

   Dossier voyage QORXSD

   LYON PART DIEU 15/06 à 18h56

   TARIF LIBERTE- Carte Libené valide à présenter . Echange et remboursement sans frais jusqu''à 30 min apres

   départ . Des 30 min avant départ , billet échangeable 2 fois max ( méme jour , même trajet ) et non remboursable

   après 1 échange . Siemprunt d''un autre train , échange obligatoire

   Ne - bile :

   Référence client

   Nº FCE

   Point de vente FRXMB

   SNCF vous remercie de votre confiance .

   2- CLASSE

   1 A sur 1 0 Page 1/1

   SNCF

   SNCF Voyageurs , société anonyme au capital social de 157 780 980 euros - rue Jean - Philippe Rameau , 93200 Saint - Denis - RCS Bobigny n 519 037 584
   '

   SELECT 1

   WHERE @raw_text LIKE '%JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE%JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE%'

As you see in your text copyied into a variable.

Firt occurrence is in UPPERCASE, second in lowercase.

If you want to distinguish upper from lower just use a collation with a CI parameter like :

COLLATE French_CI_AS

```
`SELECT 1
`WHERE @raw_text COLLATE French_CI_AS LIKE '%JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE%JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE%'`
```

Answer (score 0):

The raw text does contain the search expression twice, in rows 1 and 4. You have to specify collation for the search to be case sensitive.

I would do it like that:

```
DECLARE @SearchedForExpression nvarchar(300) = 'JUSTIFICATIF DE VOYAGE' 
DECLARE @ExpectedNumberOfOccurances int = 2

select raw_text from tableName
 WHERE (LEN(raw_text collate  Latin1_General_CS_AS ) -LEN(REPLACE(raw_text collate  Latin1_General_CS_AS ,@SearchedForExpression,''))) / LEN(@SearchedForExpression) = @ExpectedNumberOfOccurances
```